# autoprefixer PHP is not working as shown in examples

Tags: php, css, autoprefixer

I installed "autoPrefixer PHP" using composer and tried examples as shown in github page (https://github.com/vladkens/autoprefixer-php). 
the very simple example

```
$autoprefixer = new Autoprefixer();
$css      = 'a { transition: transform 1s }';
$prefixed = $autoprefixer->compile($css);
```

just outputs the $css unchanged. However if I initiliaze autprefixer object with custom parameter it outputs correctly prefixed css.

```
$autoprefixer = new Autoprefixer('last 2 versions');
```

also  initializing the object with the paramaters as shown in example, gives "unknown browser requirement 'ie8'" error

```
$autoprefixer = new Autoprefixer(array('ff > 2', '> 2%', 'ie8')); // many rules
```

so what can be wrong in my installation? in fact, I did not do anything manually, just installed by composer.

Answer (score 2):

a quick look at the code of the [vladkens Autoprefixer PHP](https://github.com/vladkens/autoprefixer-php) compile method:

```
$nodejs = proc_open('node ' . __DIR__ . '/vendor/wrap.js',
    array(array('pipe', 'r'), array('pipe', 'w')),
    $pipes
);
```

ok, proc_open node .., it uses Note.js and in vladkens readme introduction he writes:

> This library provides PHP integration with Node.js application.

and in the readme install part he writes it too

> First you need install Node.js in your server.

---

it looks like there is currently no real PHP rebuild Compiler for people without an own server, hoster whos support Note.js, experience on Grunt/Gulp with such as Compass or no mac for [CodeKit](https://incident57.com/codekit/index.html) (nice software, find it previously, but can't use it directly on linux).

When my PHP software uses scss, sass, less or other css PHP modifications with smart caching, its also a good idea to add autoprefixer.

---

**conclusion**

You need Node.js on your Server and the Permissions to execute proc_open() in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You need a space between "ie" and "8", like in the example:

```
$autoprefixer = new Autoprefixer(array('ff > 2', '> 2%', 'ie 8')); // many rules
```